# PHP MySQLi query error inside class "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given"

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried everything, I read other questions here in stackoverflow and I still cant fix this.

**I know there is plenty other questions like this and answers, but none help me! Tried over 5 hours to figure out**

Anyway I have the following:

```
class RecoverPas{

private $mysqli;

   public function __construct()    
   {

      $this->newMessage();      //Allow new object access to default Error Messages.
      $this->deleteOldCodes();  //Delete reset codes older that a certain interval.

      $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
      $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        if($this->mysqli === false)
        {
           user_error("Unable to connect to database via mysqli.");
           return false;
        } 
   }
 public function deleteOldCodes(){

    $query_deloldcodes = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "delete FROM activereset
    WHERE date  < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '".$this->deloldcodeint."' DAY)");

        if ( false===$query_deloldcodes ) {
          printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($this->mysqli));
        }

    }

}
$forgotpass = new RecoverPas();
```

About the mysqli connect , the db info is ok I defined the db info in other php file, and this mysqli conenct work in other class perfect, also I test if the defines works here and they are defined here too.

As you see I tried to print the errors but no I keep getting only this :

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in line 506
```

Line 506 is  `public function deleteOldCodes(){` that i put above ,
I dont get mysqli error so its seem That there is a conenction, and i try to printf the mysqli error and not working either.

So what wrong here?

Comment: You call `deleteOldCodes` function before `$this->mysqli` is defined, so it is `null`

Comment: You're calling `$this->deleteOldCodes();` (which uses `$this->mysqli`) **before** you setup `$this->mysqli`

Comment: $this->deleteOldCodes(); should be after checking db connection.

Comment: I will try change places,i did it from other Answers here in stackoverflaw

Comment: You all right, my mistake didnt notice i am sorry.

Comment: And this is not a good idea to call some logic in the constructor, 'cause (according to it's name) should only care to construct an object

Comment: Sidebar Overflow!  See ========>

Comment: Have to know who voted down, this man realy need to banned from stackoverflow for vote for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just experienced temporal coupling.

Switch the order of the lines in your example to match the below, that way the database connection will be initialised before you try to query it.

```
  $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

  $this->newMessage();      //Allow new object access to default Error Messages.
  $this->deleteOldCodes();  //Delete reset codes older that a certain interval.
```

Comment: I cant accept , if you dont know need to wait 10 minutes after question posted.